REAL call center conversation recordings/transcripts
I am looking for a dataset containing audio recordings and/or transcripts of real customer service calls. I require recordings/transcripts of both the customer service agent handling the call and the customer themselves. I am researching non-face-to-face human interactions and how people behave on customer service calls. The hope is that this research helps improve future "AI" bots which are likely to replace call centres completely. I have searched YouTube and various other sources, yet apart from a couple of mock calls, there is not much in the way of "real" or "actual" customer service recordings. This is strange to me since a vast majority of customer service calls are recorded for quality assurance purposes. Does anyone know of openly available or paid customer service call recording datasets?

Does this answer your question? Customer Service (Call Center) Audio datasets

These dataset are usually easy to find but this company offers a wide variety of call center datasets with audio and transcripts.
https://www.futurebeeai.com/dataset?category=speech+recognition&vtitle=telecom+call+center+speech+datasets&categorized=false
or this one
https://data.macgence.com/dataset/call-center-conversation-speech-datasets-in-english-for-phone-service-support#lead-form
Unfortunately both datasets are paid but according to the first link you can download some free samples.
